# value type of constant in Swift in layout anchors

Tags: autolayout, swift5

Just to know the difference between 10 (for example) and view.frame.height/10 (where view.frame.height is 100)

I put textView.frame.height/3 instead of of 25 in paddingTop (see code below) and the value of paddingTop becomes 0

I tried this .....

```
extension UIView

{    func anchor(   top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?,
                    left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?,
                    bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?,
                    right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?,
                    paddingTop: CGFloat,
                    paddingLeft: CGFloat,
                    paddingBottom: CGFloat,
                    paddingRight: CGFloat,
                    width: CGFloat,
                    height: CGFloat     )

    {   translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        if let top = top {   self.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: paddingTop).isActive = true   }

        if let left = left {   self.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: paddingLeft).isActive = true   }

        if let bottom = bottom {   self.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -paddingBottom).isActive = true   }

        if let right = right {   self.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -paddingRight).isActive = true   }

        if width != 0 {   widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width).isActive = true   }

        if height != 0 {   heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height).isActive = true    }

    }

...

view.addSubview(textView)

textView.anchor(top: topView.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 10, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 10, width: 0, height: view.frame.height/4)

textView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

textView.addSubview(label)
label.anchor(top:textView.topAnchor, left: textView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, paddingTop: 25, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height:textView.frame.height/5)

counterLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descrizioneTextView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are asking. Could you please state clearly what you require help with and what it is you are trying to achieve.  
Also, welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: I try to explain... I don't understand the difference between write ... paddingTop = 25 and paddingTop = textView.frame.height/5

Comment: if in the code I put directly a number (25 for example) the label has 25 from the top, if I put a value from textView.frame.height the label has 0 from the top. Thanks

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add this additional information.

Comment: I try it again... with my anchor() function if I pass to paddingTop the value of 25 as a number the code works (but probably will not work on every device), but if I pass to paddingTop the value of view.frame.heght/4 (in this way it should works on every device - I know that view's height is 100: print(view.frame.heght/4) give me 25)  my subview has no padding from the top of the view... Thanks and pls, sorry if I'm not so clear....

Answer (score 0):

So the reason why you're experiencing that problem is because at the moment you're initialising the view, the value (view.frame.height) is 0 and you can't get view.frame.height/4.

Since you're working with UIView, Try to set the padding top in this method :

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews() 
 }
```